# Help with applying lemma in proving normality of a subspace.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the theorem below with the Normality Lemma. In particular, I am having trouble with constructing the sets necessary to apply the Normality Lemma and was wondering if my approach is possible or not. And if not, what would be a valid approach? To clarify, I am supposed to be applying the Normality Lemma so any approach must use it.

> Normality Lemma. Let $A, B$ be closed disjoint subsets of $X$. Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{V_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be countable collections of open sets that cover $A$ and $B$ respectively. Furthermore, $\overline{U}_i \cap B = \overline{V}_i \cap A = \varnothing$ for all $i$. Then there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$.

> Theorem. Let $X$ be a normal space. Let $C = \cup_{i=1}^\infty K_i$ where $K_i \subset X$ is closed in $X$ for each $i$. Show $C \subset X$ endowed with the subspace topology is normal.

What I have so far:
Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint and closed in $C$. Let $K_n' = \cup_{i=1}^n K_i$. Then $K_n'$ is closed in both $X$ and $C$. Since $X$ is normal then $K_n'$ is normal. Then $A \cap K_n'$ and $B \cap K_n'$ are closed and disjoint in $K_n'$. By normality of $K_n'$ there are disjoint open sets $U_n,V_n$ such that $A \cap K_n' \subset U_n$ and $B \cap K_n' \subset V_n$. I am aware that the sets $U_n, V_n$ are not necessarily open in $C$. Somehow I need to extend $U_n,V_n$ to be open in $C$, call them $U_n', V_n'$, such that their closures don't intersect $B$ and $A$ respectively. I am not sure if I can do this or if there is a better approach. I appreciate you reading this.

Thanks!